Is there any formula for calculating the temperature required for nuclear fusion for a specific pressure?
From what I have gathered through my research I've come to the conclusion that the temperature required for nuclear fusion decreases with increasing pressure; this seems intuitive enough. However, I failed to find a direct formula for the temperature required for fusion at a specific temperature.
I would be really thankful if someone could derive/lead me to the formula.

any answer requires which fusion reaction you are talking about. It's kind of a big question for PSE. I know you can search as well as I can, but have you seen:  https://websites.pmc.ucsc.edu/~glatz/astr_112/lectures/

Center-of-mass energy is the important parameter for nuclear reactions (such as fusion). Generally that means that the Boltzman distribution based on the temperature is the only relevant parameter - pressure is pretty meaningless.

Key to getting the answer you wish is first knowing what the equation of state is for the fusion reactants. This lets you relate pressure, temperature, and density.
Please note that all equations of state are approximate and as temperature, pressure and density are increased, physical effects which were previously negligible become dominant and must be accounted for by adding more physics to the approximation.
As such, do not let anyone here assert to you that the presence of multiple equations of state which cover different conditions means that there is in fact no equation of state. This is not even wrong and is tantamount to for example the assertion that Pharaoh Ramses could not have died of tuberculosis in 1290 BC because the tuberculosis bacterium was not identified by Robert Koch until 1882.


I would be really thankful if someone could derive/lead me to the
formula.

There is none, at least no general solution.
First off though, we need to know what you mean by "temperature required for nuclear fusion". That can be two different things.
One meaning is the energy needed to overcome the Coulomb barrier for a given fuel. There is a formula for this, which you can find here. This is largely a function of the atomic mass and nuclear charge.
The typical way to supply this level of energy is to heat the fuel until some of the atoms have more than this amount of kinetic energy. Since the atoms will follow the Maxwell–Boltzmann distribution, you can calculate a temperature that produces any given fraction of the fuel having that energy.
I'm not aware of any dependency of the Coulomb barrier energy with pressure, at least for any sort of pressure we can produce on Earth. I'm no expert on stellar astrophysics, but I don't think the energy needed for fusion changes even in the ridiculous conditions within a supernova.
But I don't think that is what you are referring to here when you speak of temperature and pressure. I believe you mean this...
Hot objects radiate away energy through a variety of processes. Hotter objects do so faster. This presents a difficulty for fusion reactors because the fuel is always cooling down naturally and it requires the constant addition of more heat to keep it from cooling too far down to have any atoms left with enough KE to overcome the Coulomb barrier.
There is some help available. In the common D-T reaction, for instance, one of the things that comes out of the fusion reaction is an alpha particle. This is charged and is trapped by the same magnets that are holding the fuel in the reactor. It's also very high energy, much higher than the surrounding fuel ions. As it goes spinning about the reactor it hits these other atoms and heats them up. This is called "thermalizing".
So we have one effect that's cooling the plasma off and another that is heating it back up. There is, for common fusion fuels, a point where the two become equal. This is known as "ignition". This isn't a fixed point, it has to do with the rates of everything. As you heat the fuel up there will be more atoms with more energy than the Coulomb barrier and thus the rate of fusion increases, so there are more alphas and more heat, but that higher temperature also means the fuel is losing more heat through various processes. When you plot the two functions on a graph you normally end up with a lenticular shape where the fuel is ignited.
Ok, pressure. It's not really pressure that comes into play, but density. Typical fusion reactors use almost no fuel, a few grams filling a huge reactor. The conditions are described as a "very good vacuum". So when the alpha is released, it takes some time before it bumps into enough atoms to lose its energy and heat up the fuel. In a steady state, this doesn't really make a difference because we're talking microseconds for a reactor that's running for seconds.
However, if that fuel is extremely dense, like 100 times the density of lead, then the alphas almost immediately hit another atom. They give up their energy into the fuel in nanoseconds. So the reaction rate is thousands of times faster.
So back to this:

the temperature required for nuclear fusion decreases with increasing
pressure

So what is going on is not direct. It's not that the pressure is causing the temperature to create fusion is being lowered. It's that to make more energy that you lose, you need to maintain a particular rate of fusion. And that rate can be increased with increased temperature and by increased density.
So if you wish to reach rate R, you can do so using 1 temperature + 0.5 density, or perhaps 0.5 temperature and 1 density. The relationship is not linear because the former is the Maxwell–Boltzmann distribution, which is a curve, while the second is mostly.
What you are really looking for is this term: Lawson criterion. That article explains all of this in more depth.
